# Calling IBM Cloud Function in United Kingdom from Watson Assistant gives: The supplied authentication is invalid

Tags: authentication, ibm-cloud, watson-assistant, ibm-cloud-functions

I am getting this error:

> The supplied authentication is invalid

when we are calling an IBM Cloud Function running in the United Kingdom region from a dialog node in the Watson Assistant (also in the UK)

The strange thing is, that when we call a Cloud Function that runs in US South, (with different credentials) it works fine.

Calling the Cloud Function (UK instance) from PostMan works fine as well.

The difference with PostMan is, that we provide the complete endpoint URL.

In the Watson Assistant dialog node we "only" supply the part after "namespaces". Due to the limit of 64 characters for the name, we cannot provide the entire URL. 
I suspect the Watson Assistant run time to try US-South first (even if it runs in the UK) and when it finds a namespace it tries to access this one ?! But this is just a thought...

For now we can use the Cloud Function in the US (south), but I am looking for a way to get this to work for the UK as well?

--- update ----
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately cloud functions are not currently available in any region other than us south. We are working to develop a pipeline for all regions but not at this time

Comment: Hi @Mitch, I have edited the question to include a screenshot which shows Cloud Functions in the UK ?

Comment: Watson assistant is currently not available directly in uk. It is available in the region but syndicated back to us. The pipeline we wrote service side cannot connect these two at this time.

Comment: When I said cloud functions are not available I should have been more clear as well. Cloud functions inside Watson assistant are only available in us south at this time